# How to construct SQL script for selecting all id references that are part of one citation rope?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Just imagine table that contains rows e.g. as follows:

[image]

```
SELECT ? AS distinct_connected_numbers 
FROM dependency_table 
WHERE article_id = 410 OR ref_article_id = 410
```

And result should be (order is important too for me):

```
id | distinct_connected_numbers 
1  | 412
2  | 411
3  | 410
```

or

```
SELECT ? AS distinct_connected_numbers 
FROM dependency_table 
WHERE article_id = 420 OR ref_article_id = 420
```

And ordered result should be:

```
id | distinct_connected_numbers 
1  | 421
2  | 420
3  | 417
```

The numbers in **article_id** and **ref_article_id** columns can occur more than once, but in result I need distinct numbers. Please, how to select from this table all numbers (one number per row in result set) that have same citation dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select 410 as article_id, 1 as lev
      from dependency_table dt
      union all
      select dt.article_id, 1 + lev
      from cte join
           dependency_table dt
           on cte.article_id = dt.ref_article_id
     )
select distinct t.article_id,
       (max(lev) over () - lev) as id
from cte;
```

Comment: select DISTINCT article_id, (max(lev) over () - lev) as id from cte; ... and it works, thanks